# Change twentytwelve sidebar responsive relocation?

Tags: sidebar, responsive

I'm using twentytwelve as a base theme and I want to change a behavior of the sidebar. When viewing in mobile view (you can collapse your browser window all the way horizontally  to see the same view) the sidebar items drop below the content. I would like one item (the top item) of my sidebar to go above the content but stand under the navigation. So for example say I have recent posts, recent comments and subscribe in my sidebar. When in mobile view I want recent posts to stay on top of the content, and recent comments and subscribe to go below. Is this possible?

Thanks a bunch for any and all help!
Best,
George

Answer (score 1):

The fast way to do this is to just change how it is loaded, open index.php and move this code:

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

From line 73 and put it under `get_header(); ?>` around line 18, so it should look like:

```
get_header(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
// rest of twentytwelve code.
```

Ps. I highly recommend you create a child theme so when you update the theme, the changes you make do not break.

Comment: hey thanks for helping out. That will work but the problem is I don't want my entire sidebar loaded above my content. Strictly just one of a couple widgets. Is this possible?

Comment: Not without creating a new sidebar, also this technique might break when the theme is updated.